# How to make python program run automatically every time I download a file?

Tags: python

I want to create a program that runs automatically every time I download a file from browser.

For example, when I download an image file from chrome, the program runs automatically and perform tasks. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly you want to do. May be you can look in to crontab in ubuntu.

Comment: [This](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) looks promising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a script using len(os.listdir()) to see how many files are in your downloads folder, and anytime that number changes, perform your desired operation on the newest file

EDIT:

You'd want a Python script looking something like this:

```py
import time
import os
While True:
    NumberOfFiles=len(os.listdir("C:\Path\To\Downloads\Folder"))
    time.sleep(20)
    OldNumber = NumberOfFiles
    NumberOfFiles = len(os.listdir("C:\Path\To\Downloads\Folder"))
    if NumberOfFiles != OldNumber:
        #This is where you put the lines of code you want executed when you download something.
```

And then you'd need a .bat file with something like

```
C:\Path\To\Python C:\Path\To\That\Script
```

You could put that .bat file in your Startup folder, or use the Task Scheduler utility to make it start running everytime you log on to your computer.

Hope this helps!  At the moment it checks for new files only once every 20 seconds. You could make that check more often by lowering the number there, but the more often it checks, the more resources this is gonna use. If you don't download things to often, I'd even suggest changing it to something like 60

Comment: That's a Great idea! But can you kindly tell me how can I make the program monitor the files in download folder continuously? Like, it should start monitoring when my computer starts and end when I shut down?  Grateful for response!

Comment: I'd need to know your operating system for that part.

Comment: It's a 32-bit OS

Comment: Sorry, I had meant if you use Windows, Linux, etc.

Comment: Oh! I use Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

I think you need some kind of "listening" script running on background which will monitor files in download directory